# How to use Entity on a Page Module?

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

i want to use Entity{} on Page{}, this because i want to click a button and show another page that have the Qt3D model , please help how i can do it with stackview, stackview only read pages not Just Entity Module ! ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use Scene3D in Page to use Qt3D.